# when i run this code, its say that thefuction countChecked undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want that when i click the checkbox the value on it will be display into the dropdown below. please help me. thank you

```
window.onload = function countChecked() {
  var n = $("input.theme:checked").length;
  if (n == 1) {
    $('input.theme:checkbox:not(:checked)').prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $('input.theme:checkbox:not(:checked)').prop('disabled', false);
  }
}
$("input.theme:checkbox").click(countChecked);

$('.Go').click(function() {

  var i=1;
  $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){
  $('select#list'+i).val($(this).val());
  i++;
  });

});

this is the first html for checkbox

    <input class="theme" type="checkbox" name="theme" value="Present" id="Present" />
<label for="Present">Present</label>
<input class="theme" type="checkbox" name="theme" value="Absent" id="Absent" />
<label for="Absent">Absent</label>
<input class="theme" type="checkbox" name="theme" value="Leave" id="Leave" />
<label for="Leave">Leave</label>
<input class="theme" type="checkbox" name="theme" value="Holiday" id="Holiday" />
<label for="Holiday">Holiday</label>
  <br><br> <input type="button" class="Go" value="Go" />
```

this is another html for dropdown

```
    <select id='list1' name='att_status[]'>
      <option value='Present'>Present</option>
      <option value='Absent'>Absent</option>
      <option value='Holiday'>Holiday</option>
      <option value='Leave'>Leave</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Why are you using window.onload? Did you debug your code?

Comment: Or just this:  `$("input.theme:checkbox").on("click",function() { $('input.theme:checkbox:not(:checked)').prop('disabled',$("input.theme:checked").length==1)});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input.theme:checkbox").click(countChecked);

  $('.Go').click(function() {
    var i=1;
    $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){
      $('select#list'+i).val($(this).val());
      i++;
    });
    });
});

function countChecked() {
  var n = $("input.theme:checked").length;
  if (n == 1) {
    $('input.theme:checkbox:not(:checked)').prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $('input.theme:checkbox:not(:checked)').prop('disabled', false);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey why are you doing this?
`window.onload = function(){}`
This code set to window.onload property a function.
You must define that function like this:

```js
$("input.theme:checkbox").click(countChecked);

$('.Go').click(function() {

  var i=1;
  $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){
  $('select#list'+i).val($(this).val());
  i++;
  });

});

function countChecked() {
  var n = $("input.theme:checked").length;
  if (n == 1) {
    $('input.theme:checkbox:not(:checked)').prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $('input.theme:checkbox:not(:checked)').prop('disabled', false);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="theme" type="checkbox" name="theme" value="Present" id="Present" />
<label for="Present">Present</label>
<input class="theme" type="checkbox" name="theme" value="Absent" id="Absent" />
<label for="Absent">Absent</label>
<input class="theme" type="checkbox" name="theme" value="Leave" id="Leave" />
<label for="Leave">Leave</label>
<input class="theme" type="checkbox" name="theme" value="Holiday" id="Holiday" />
<label for="Holiday">Holiday</label>
  <br><br> <input type="button" class="Go" value="Go" />
  
 <br>
 <br>
      <select id='list1' name='att_status[]'>

                                <option value='Present'>Present</option>
                                <option value='Absent'>Absent</option>
                                <option value='Holiday'>Holiday</option>
                                <option value='Leave'>Leave</option>
                            </select>
```

Comment: when i run this code it say that $ is not define. thats why i put the window.onload. thank you for answering my question.

Comment: If you read the [mdn onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) it says that function assign like this `window.onload = countChecked(){}` will fire up after load event fires.Thats fine but then you wanted to use this function even though it wasnt defined in that scope.Cheers!